# InfoPath Validation Error on older list items: Only 'true' or 'false' allowed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, infopath, infopath2010

I have a custom SharePoint 2013 list (which started as a SP2010 list) with roughly 2,000 items. It was recently brought to my attention that I am having a strange issue with a check box/boolean type. I can't recall if it was originally created as a Yes/No column in SharePoint before the web form was created in InfoPath.

The field name is Report Received. Up until now, and only for troubleshooting, the checkbox was never actually on the form. I had a rule where if a question was answered, the field value was set to 'true' in lowercase without quotes.

If I create new item in the list, the checkbox works as expected.

If I attempt to edit a previous item that the value was already false, I get a validation error upon save, that states that only 'true' or 'false' is allowed.

In conclusion, I can only assume that for a period of time, something was buggy in my rule/form/field.
My goal is to either set that field to blank on the items, or fix the assumed corruption in the field on those items.

Fortunately, I don't have many items to fix.

One idea i had was to create a view called "Test". 
On that view i dragged the Report Received field on the form. I also added a calculated field below it which shows me the current value of the field, and 3 buttons, each with a rule, to either set the value to blank, set it to false (lowercase), set it to true (lowercase).
I then opened an old item that is giving me the error, to test my new buttons.
My first observation is that the calculated field indicates that the value is currently false (lowercase)
Unfortunately, when i click any of them, i instantly see that the checkbox turns red, indicating that only 'true' or 'false' is allowed when i mouse over the checkbox.
The strange thing is that my calculated field indicates that the value changed to TRUE in uppercase, even though the box is unchecked. 
I am noticing this before attempting to save the form.

If I create a new item in this list, and go to my "test' view, the buttons work just fine.

While InfoPath seems to prefer true and false, the value in the SharePoint lists are Yes and No.

Any ideas how I may be able remove the corruption on these older list items, without deleting and recreating them?
I am currently using InfpoPath 2010 to edit the form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am kicking myself. I ran Rule Inspector and saw that a rule i was not aware of was causing my issues. I deleted it, and now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info.  I was experiencing the same thing and was able to find my error as well by using Rule Inspector.  More specifically, my issue was being caused by a rule running on the "submit" buttons that set the checkbox or boolean field to "Yes" to match what was in SharePoint.  I found that you have to actually use the formula (*fx*) field in InfoPath and enter `boolean("true")` as the formula to get InfoPath to pass the value correctly to SharePoint!